# Not able to run the beam job written on java on portable flink runner

Tags: apache-flink, apache-beam, grpc-java, apache-beam-io

I am trying to run a beam job on a portable Flink runner

> executed the runner by the below command :
>
> ```
> docker run --net=host apache/beam_flink1.10_job_server:latest --flink-master=localhost:8081
> ```

Then tried to run the beam job by passing the below arguments:

```
--runner=PortableRunner --jobEndpoint=http://192.168.63.100:8099
```

followed this [link](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/runners/flink/) to set up the job.

It is giving the below error on the start up:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: cannot find a NameResolver for http://192.168.63.100:8099
at org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p21p0.io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImpl.getNameResolver(ManagedChannelImpl.java:694)
at org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p21p0.io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImpl.<init>(ManagedChannelImpl.java:571)
at org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p21p0.io.grpc.internal.AbstractManagedChannelImplBuilder.build(AbstractManagedChannelImplBuilder.java:514)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.fn.channel.ManagedChannelFactory.forDescriptor(ManagedChannelFactory.java:44)
at org.apache.beam.runners.portability.PortableRunner.run(PortableRunner.java:193)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.run(Pipeline.java:315)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.run(Pipeline.java:301)
```

Answer (score 0):

The instruction provided in the link is for a local setup. The jobEndpoint you provided is a class C ip address. Since you are using the PortableRunner and it complains about missing a NameResolver (but you don't have control of the Java code), try using a domain name such as "localhost" instead of the ip address.

Comment: I am running the docker with docker-machine in VM, I don't think I can provide localhost, any other alternative? @ningk

Comment: You are running the docker container with the host network that serves the job server API. Can you try exposing the ports with the `docker run` command then using localhost or 127.0.0.1 since your job submission is on the host machine itself? E.g., `docker run -p 8099:8099 -p 8081:8081 --net=host apache/beam_flink1.10_job_server:latest --flink-master=localhost:8081`. Also, you can directly use FlinkRunner (for Python portable) without going through the PortableRunner.